how can we change color of specific column values in salesforce analytics lens
In Salesforce Analytics, I have configured an action for the 'Case Number' column in a lens. I want to change the color of this column, similar to the blue color used for hyperlinks, so that users can easily identify which column has an actionable link associated with it. How can I achieve this.

The "case number" in my case is a text column and when I try to do conditional formatting in this column, it is not displaying any color which I can set for "case number" column.



Edit the Lens
Select the Chart: Click on the chart or table where you want to apply conditional formatting.
Open the Formatting Pane: Look for the formatting pane or options.
This may be on the right-hand side or accessible through a menu.
Set up Conditional Formatting > Save

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quick-start-einstein-analytics/apply-conditional-formatting

@Shradda In my case the "case number" is a text column and when I try to do conditional formatting in this column, it is not displaying any color which I can set for my "case number" column. attached screen shot for your reference.
